# Ajax post to Razor page backend not working

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor

I need to post an id from my view to the back end razor page and im not sure what i'm doing wrong i keep getting 404 error.
Here is my code :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteHourLine(int? id)
    {
        HourEntryModel hourEntryModel = _context.HourEntryModel.Where(m => m.ID == 
        id).FirstOrDefault();
        _context.HourEntryModel.Remove(hourEntryModel);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return new RedirectToPageResult("Index");
    }
```

Ajax:

```
 function DeleteHourLine(obj)
    {
        var ele = $(obj);
        var id = ele.data("model-id");
      
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            url: '?handler=DeleteHourLine',
            data: { int: id },
            success: function (data) {
                ele.closest("tr").remove();
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        })
    }
```

HTML razor code:

```
            <td>
                <img id="DeleteHourLine" onclick="DeleteHourLine(this)" data-model-id="@item.ID" 
                src="~/delete-16.png" />
            </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly,you need to change `DeleteHourLine` to `OnPostDeleteHourLineAsync`.The default convention works by matching the HTTP verb used for the request to the name of the method, which is prefixed with "On": `OnGet()`, `OnPost()`, `OnPut()` etc.And you can add `Async` suffix on methods that contain asynchronous code.

And you need to remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`,because you don't post data in body.

Then you need to change `data: { int: id },` to `data: { id: id },`,because you use `int? id` in handler.

Last but not least,you need to add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` to your page,and add `headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },` to your ajax.Razor Pages are designed to be protected from (CSRF/XSRF) attacks,so Antiforgery token generation and validation are automatically included in Razor Pages.

Here is a demo:

view(I use `1` as sample data,and add `@Html.AntiForgeryToken()` so that can get antiforgery token in the view):

```
<td>
    <img id="DeleteHourLine" onclick="DeleteHourLine(this)" data-model-id="1"
         src="~/imgs/2.jpg" />
</td>
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

ajax:

```
function DeleteHourLine(obj) {
        var ele = $(obj);
        var id = ele.data("model-id");

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '?handler=DeleteHourLine',
            headers: { "RequestVerificationToken": $('input[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() },
            data: { id: id },
            success: function (data) {
                ele.closest("tr").remove();
            },
            error: function (result) {
                alert("fail");
            }
        })
    }
```

handler:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostDeleteHourLineAsync(int? id)
        {
            
            return new RedirectToPageResult("Index");
        }
```

result:
[image]